# Python: Removing lower versions from a 2D list

Tags: python, list

Assume I have the following data structure (a list of lists):

`myList = [['Something','1'], ['Something','2'], ['Something Else','5'], ['Yet Another Something','1'], ['Yet ANOTHER Something','0'], ['Yet Another Something','2']]`

I have a function that will remove duplicates from that list, choosing the highest number for the 2nd value. However, it seems to choke on very large data sets (150+ entries in myList). For this small data set, I expect the returned list to be:

`[['Something','2'], ['Something Else','5'], ['Yet Another Something','2']]`

What kind of optimization can be implemented using standard python (without including custom, external modules) into this function so that it returns the same result set without issues on large data sets?

Here is my function:

```
def remove_duplicates(duplicate): 
    final_list = []
    final_list_upper = []
    for k,v in duplicate: 
        found = False
        for x in range(len(final_list)):
            if k in final_list[x] or k.upper() in final_list_upper[x]:
                if k == final_list[x][0] or k.upper() == final_list_upper[x][0]:
                    if int(v) >= int(final_list[x][1]):
                        final_list.pop(final_list.index(final_list[x]))
                        final_list_upper.pop(final_list_upper.index(final_list_upper[x]))
                        break
                    else:
                        found = True
                        break
        if not found:
            final_list.append([k,v]) 
            final_list_upper.append([k.upper(),v])
    final_list_upper = [] # clear the list
    return final_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a second loop to check if the current "key" that you're checking exists in the list. This is slowing down your code.
Why? Because, as your code demonstrates, checking for membership in lists is *slow*. **Really slow,** because you need to iterate over the entire list, which means it's an O(N) operation, so the time depends linearly on the size of the list.

Instead, you could simply change the list to a dictionary. Lookup in a dictionary is an O(1) operation, so the lookup happens in constant (or nearly constant) time regardless of the size of the dictionary.
When you do this, there's no longer a need for two loops. Here's an idea:

```
def remove_duplicates_new(duplicate): 
    final_dict = {}
    case_sensitive_keys = {}
    for k, v in duplicate: 
        klower = k.lower()
        vint = int(v)
        old_val = final_dict.get(klower, 0) # Get the key k, with a default of zero if the key doesn't exist
        if vint > old_val:
            # Replace if current value is greater than old value
            final_dict[klower] = vint
            case_sensitive_keys[klower] = k
        
    # Now we're done looping, so create the list
    final_list = [[case_sensitive_keys[k], str(v)] for k, v in final_dict.items()]
    return final_list
```

To compare, let's make a test list with 10000 elements. The "keys" are random numbers between 1 and 100, so we're bound to get a whole bunch of duplicates.:

```
import random
import timeit

testList = [[str(random.randint(1, 100)), str(random.randint(1, 10))] for i in range(10000)]

timeit.timeit('remove_duplicates(testList)', setup='from __main__ import testList, remove_duplicates', number=10)
# Output: 1.1064800999999989

timeit.timeit('remove_duplicates_new(testList)', setup='from __main__ import testList, remove_duplicates_new', number=10)
# Output:  0.03743689999998878
```

Hot damn! That's a ~30x speedup!

Comment: I would also mention computational complexity: the complexity of checking if an element is in a list is O(N) (checking all N elements), checking in a dictionary is O(1) (through magical properties of dictionaries and hashing).

Comment: @danuker good point! I thought I already mentioned it. I guess I'm not as awake as I thought I am

Comment: @PranavHosangadi this is great, thank you! Running this against my large data set, this has definitely increased speed significantly.